# Sorting with custom date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to fetch information in my database. Each row has a date formatted as   like January 2013. How to I sort them such as the latest date will be given first? These information weren't inserted in order that's why they need to be sorted first. Thank you! :)

Comment: do you have date or only month and year present on the value?

Comment: convert those "custom" dates to a native date/datetime/timestamp field and your problem basically goes away. **NEVER** store custom formats when a native format will work.

Comment: I used varchar for the dates. Thank you for this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stored date in `varchar`. so use `STR_TO_DATE()` function for sorting

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column, %M %Y) ORDER BY column DESC
```

Comment: I used this because i couldn't change the structure anymore. This works fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Date formatting is irrelevant as long as you keep your date in column of proper type like TIMESTAMP, DATE etc. If your date is kept in i.e. VARCHAR, then your database is simply broken and you shall fix column type at first.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is kind of tricky but it think it is the only way since you have varchar as datatype in your table. It works, but i'm not sure about the performance with large scale table data.
The trick is to break your varchar into 2 mumber fields, one with the year and with the month number.

```
SELECT mydate
FROM mytable
ORDER BY RIGHT(mydate,4) DESC, //get the year
CASE LEFT(mydate,INSTR(mydate,' ')-1)
WHEN 'January' THEN 1
WHEN 'February' THEN 2
WHEN 'March' THEN 3
WHEN 'April' THEN 4
WHEN 'May' THEN 5
WHEN 'June' THEN 6
WHEN 'July' THEN 7
WHEN 'August' THEN 8 
WHEN 'September' THEN 9
WHEN 'October' THEN 10
WHEN 'November' THEN 11
WHEN 'December' THEN 12
END DESC //get the month and turn in to number
```